# SonarQube LDAP plugin clean up inactive users

Tags: ldap, sonarqube, active-directory-group

LDAP plugin works as expected in SonarQube and now authentication is working fine with AD groups.

Now few users are deleted from given group but it is still showing up in Sonar user list and part of given group **until** same user try to login and then Sonar Sync it with AD groups and if not part of that group, it will be removed automatically from that group.

I want to know if there is any way to execute sync between AD and

- Users will be removed from group for which he/she is not part of AD group?
- If user is not part of any group will be deleted from Sonar user list

Answer (score 0):

I do confirm that your understanding of the behavior of the SonarQube LDAP plugin is correct ! And no there isn't any way to do some background sync with AD. If you want to talk about a potential solution/approach, please start a thread on the SonarQube Google Group : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I will post my query as you suggested